# Post-methods to integrate Lazy Registration with django-registration

Tags: django, django-registration, lazy-registration

I'm using [the tutorial at this link](http://tartarus.org/james/diary/2009/07/24/implementing-deferred-registration-with-django) to do my lazy-registration, and I'm trying to combine it with [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/).

The tutorial at the lazy-registration link simply needs to call one command to re-parent the events saved:

```
def on_registration_complete(self, request):
    Wishlist.reparent_all_my_session_objects(request.session, request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def on_login_complete(self, request, user, openid=None):
    Wishlist.reparent_all_my_session_objects(request.session, request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

How do I do a post-hook with django-registration to call `reparent_all_my_session_objects()` command after the user logs in or registers?  Do I need to create my own **auth** by copying from **django.contrib.auth**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to create your own signal receivers on registration and login.

```
# Handle the signal sent by user_login
from registration.signals import user_login, user_registered
from events.models import Event
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

# Use the signal sent after the login wrapper
def user_login_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    """signal intercept for user_login"""
    request = kwargs['request']
    Event.reparent_all_my_session_objects(request.session, request.user)

def user_registered_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    """signal intercept for user_registered"""
    request = kwargs['request']
    # Authenticate user, so that a User model (instead of AnonymousUser) is assigned to Event
    # Registration form validates password1==password2
    new_user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
    login(request, new_user)
    Event.reparent_all_my_session_objects(request.session, new_user)

user_login.connect(user_login_handler)
user_registered.connect(user_registered_handler)
```